# Find element by label using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I got a button named "Photos" that I want to find through Selenium:

```
<label class="Label" id="item--label">Photos</label>
```

I tried to find it through XPath but I got the code below (which repeats in more buttons in the page):

```
//*[@id="item--label"]
```

Is there a way to locate the item by label?

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('Photos')
```

But no success.

If anyone could help, I would be glad!

Thanks!

Comment: But that doesn't look like a button. Can you show the HTML including the button you want to click?

Comment: Can you share HTML in text format here ? Or Page url if applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most complete XPath expression for this element is

```
//label[@class="label" and(@id = "item--label") and(text()="Photos")]
```

So to find it with Selenium you can use this command:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@class="label" and(@id = "item--label") and(text()="Photos")]')
```

But you definitely do not need to mention all these attributes

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//label[text()='Photos']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

```
//*[@id="item--label" and text()="Photos"]
```